# WordPress - Storing URL in transient is not constant

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to store current URL in transient, so I can access it for later use (when I need to link back to that page from search page).

**Code:**

```
if(!is_page_template('search.php')) {
    set_transient( 'last_url', $current_url, 60*60 );
}
```

So this code should save current url of current page, until we are on search page.

However, once I click on the search page, `'last_url'` will become domain.tld/search. I have no idea why is that happening when I explicitly have the rule `if(!is_page_template('search.php'))`

However, my temporary solution is to check if there is also word search in URL, and if there isn't then create transient, like:

```
if(!is_page_template('search.php')) {
    if(stripos($current_url, 'search') === false) {
        set_transient( 'shop_last_url', $current_url, 60*60 );
    }
}
```

While this solution works, its the bad one since search page have different slug - for example if there are several languages...

I have also tried to use cookies and sessions without any luck.

Comment: 1. Where have you put this code? Which hook? Put whole function please. 2. are you sure that you have a file called search.php? 3. Are you sure that your theme or plugin (f.e. woocommerce) uses that search.php? It can easily be changed to custom search template by any plugin.

Comment: 1. Right now it's in header.php. I have tried also with functions.php - add_action( 'init', 'my_function', 1); 2. Yes, I have search.php, its page template.

Comment: Add this line to your code and tell us what you get printed when you enter yo search page:  echo get_page_template();

Comment: Its /wwwroot/wp-content/themes/mytheme/search.php

Comment: It's happening also when I try to use some other page templates, like Woocommerce My Account pages. In that case, I used the rule: if(!is_account_page())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your theme doesn't uses default WordPress queries ($wp_query) then the functions such as is_page_template,get_page_template_slug would not work properly.

You can see it in corresponding Core code [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/#source).

So, for your current case you can use global template variable instead.

```
if (basename($GLOBALS["template"])=='search.php'){
 set_transient( 'last_url', $current_url, 60*60 );
}
```

or

```
if (basename(get_page_template())=='search.php'){
     set_transient( 'last_url', $current_url, 60*60 );
    }
```

Comment: Not working. On page refresh 'last_url' becomes domain.tld/search. I don't know why it is not detecting that's on the search page. Code right now looks like  `add_action('wp', 'last_url_function');
    function last_url_function() {
     $current_url = getAddress();
     if (basename(get_page_template()) != 'search.php'){
      set_transient( 'last_url', $current_url, 60*60 );
     }
    }`

Comment: I also noticesed that $current_url contain `/undefined` string, so when I hit search page `last_url` is now `domain.tld/lastpage/undefined`

Comment: Strange. I have tested the code before putting an answer. It worked ok. May be there is some problem in your website environment which breaks something during wp loading.

Comment: Perhaps. I will test it on new install and default theme with no plugins.

Comment: Yup, both your and mine code works fine on clean install.

Comment: It turned out that the following code made this problem: `wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js', array(), '3.2.1', false );`

Comment: You should not use external jQuery library. It is against WP Codex

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't know that! I will mark your answer as accepted since it works as expected in normal conditions.